# Is there a way to specify alternative path for file in HTTP (cache) responce?

Tags: http, cache-control

The idea is to optimize caching behavior, so when there is a request for big file `/my/10/file1.txt`, server can specify that the same file can be used as response for `/my/current/file1.txt` ?

Are there any other 'standard'/'widely used' mechanisms to achieve the same (there are too many requests for both locations, so adding redirect is not acceptable solution).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to indicate that a response for one URL can also be used to satisfy requests for a different URL.

The [spec includes the requirement](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111#section-4) that that:

> the presented target URI ([Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-7.1) of [[HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110)]) and that of the stored response match

A response can [*invalidate* other URLs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111#name-invalidating-stored-respons):

> In particular, the URI(s) in the Location and Content-Location response header fields (if present) are candidates for invalidation

You ask for other options:

> Are there any other 'standard'/'widely used' mechanisms to achieve the same (there are too many requests for both locations, so adding redirect is not acceptable solution).

Use of redirection is exactly one possible mechanism here, and perhaps one you could reconsider. Make `current/file.txt` redirect with a 307 over to `10/file.txt`. Add `cache-control` headers so that requests to `current` are valid for an appropriate amount of time for your application, so users pick up changes. Make responses for a specific version (e.g. `10`) cached for a long time.

A typical request will ask for `current` and, if it's redirected to the version it already has, will use the cached version.